# WordPress Plugin: How to create a new subpage?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i have to write a WordPress plugin which should provide a new subpage with some kind of contact form. The plugins I've made yet only changed something in the existing files using the hooks and I don't know how to create a new subpage which is embedded into the main Wordpress layout. The plugin should also add a link to this subpage into the main navigation of the blog.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's pretty annoying but... You can't make a page on the actual blog in a plugin you make. you can however, make a shortcode like `[contact-form]` that will output the form. The user just needs to put that shortcode on a page and it will put the form there. Some reference for shortcodes can be found here: [ShortCode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). But the main syntax for creating a shortcode is this:

```
//[foobar]
function foobar_func( $atts ){
 return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

Just put the form code inside the function and change the name. You don't need attributes though. For your case you would just need to do something like this:

```
function contact_form(){
 //Code that process form
 //Actual code that outputs the form
}
```

And there you go! Thanks!

Ethan Brouwer